# Give back mummy the socks

Tags: word-order

He took his mother's socks away.

> "Give back mummy the socks."
>
> "Give mummy back the socks."

Which one is correct? Or both correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The first sentence is incorrect although you could use *give back* like this:**

*Give back the socks to Mummy.*

**Alternatively, you could say:**

*Give Mummy back the socks.*

**Or:**

*Give the socks back to Mummy.*

**The second sentence is correct.**

*Give Mummy back the socks.*

(I am a native Br/Australian English speaker with lots of experience – in life and editing.)

Comment: You could also say, "**Give the socks back to mummy**"